# Adding numbers represented as strings in a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var x = {jason: ["2", "5"], alice: ["12", "35"], samuel: ["32", "132"]}
```

I am trying to add the numbers for each key so I am doing

```
var out = 0;
    $.each(x, function (key, value) {
        out += key + ':';
        $.each(value, function (key, value) {
            out += parseInt(value, 10);
        });

    });

console.log(out)
```

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/1ezwwnm1/5/

It is adding them as strings. So instead of jason = 7 I am getting jason = 25 and so on
Cant seem to figure out what am I doing wrong

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @AlexPan -- Desired output would be jason:7 alice:47 samuel: 164

Comment: If u r using like javascript object var x = {jason: [2, 5]} or using as a json just convert from string to object like var x = JSON.stringify(x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cycle over the [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the values:

```js
var x = { "jason": [ "2", "5" ], "alice": [ "12", "35" ], "samuel": [ "32", "132" ] };

Object.keys( x ).forEach( function ( key ) {
  x[ key ] = x[ key ].reduce( function ( a, b ) {
    return ( +a ) + ( +b );
  });
});

document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify( x );
```

Comment: @Jonathan-- this is pretty cool...and the best part is its pure JS

Answer (score 3):

You are reconverting them to strings when adding them to the string `out`. To prevent this, sum all numbers, then append it to the string.

```
var out = "";
    $.each(x, function (key, value) {
        out += key + ':';
        var num = 0;
        $.each(value, function (key, value) {
            num += parseInt(value, 10);
        });
        out += num;
    });

console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

You start with `out` being `0`. As soon as you add a string to it (in this instance, `key`), it gets converted to a string; and after that you just keep concatenating further strings.

You need to separate the variable that you keep for string output from a variable that calculates a sum for you. This is a minimal modification of your code:

```
var out = "";
$.each(x, function (key, value) {
    out += key + ':';
    var sum = 0;
    $.each(value, function (key, value) {
        sum += parseInt(value, 10);
    });
    out += sum + " ";
});
console.log(out);
```

A bit nicer solution would involve functional approach:

```
var out = Object.keys(x).map(function(key) {
  return key + ":" +
      x[key].reduce(function(a, b) { return a + parseInt(b, 10); }, 0);
}).join(' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the output asked for in your comment:

```
var x = {jason: ["2", "5"], alice: ["12", "35"], samuel: ["32", "132"]}


var out = {};
    $.each(x, function (key, value) {
        out[key] = 0;
        $.each(value, function (key2, value) {
            out[key] += parseInt(value, 10);
        });

    });

console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all the other solutions, you can also use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to compute the sum.

```
var x = {
    jason: ["2", "5"],
    alice: ["12", "35"],
    samuel: ["32", "132"]
}

var out = {};
$.each(x, function (key, value) {
    out[key] = value.reduce(function (a, b) { return +a + +b; }); // <-- +a is same as parseInt(a, 10)
});

alert(JSON.stringify(out));
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/1ezwwnm1/14/**

Answer (score 0):

You are adding numbers to a string, Take integer temp as 0, add numbers to it, and then add it back to the string out

```
out =0
out+="key"
```

converts out to a string

try this:-

```
var x = {jason: ["2", "5"], alice: ["12", "35"], samuel: ["32", "132"]}
var out = "";
    $.each(x, function (key, value) {
        out += key + ':';
        temp = 0;
        $.each(value, function (key, value) {
            temp += parseInt(value, 10);
        });
        out += temp;

    });

console.log(out)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1ezwwnm1/8/

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var x = {jason: ["2", "5"], alice: ["12", "35"], samuel: ["32", "132"]}
var out = '';
$.each(x, function (key, value) {
    var counter = 0;
    $.each(value, function (key1, value1) {
        counter += parseInt(value1, 10);
    });
    out += key + ':' + counter + ' ';
});

console.log(out)
//jason:7 alice:47 samuel:164
```

Answer (score 0):

You're appending strings in your example. I have updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ezwwnm1/9/).

```
    var x = {jason: ["2", "5"], alice: ["12", "35"], samuel: ["32", "132"]}


    var out = 0;
    $.each(x, function (key, value) {
        out += key + ':';
        var sum = 0;
        $.each(value, function (key, value) {
            sum += parseInt(value, 10);
        });
        out += sum;    
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out

```
var x = {jason: ["2", "5"], alice: ["12", "35"], samuel: ["32", "132"]};
var out = {};
for(var i in x){
    out[i] = parseInt(x[i][0])+parseInt(x[i][1]);
}
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = {jason: ["2", "5"], alice: ["12", "35"], samuel: ["32", "132"]};
var str = 0;
$.each(x, function (key, value) {
    str += key + ':';
    var out = 0;
    $.each(value, function (key, value) {
        out += parseInt(value, 10);
    });
    str += out;
});
console.info(str);
```

is that your designed?

Comment: yes..although str should be a string..otherwise it adds a weird 0 in the beginning

Comment: `var str;` instand of `var str=0;`

Answer (score 0):

You are appending all the the values in the string,
you need to get the get the sum then append that to the key.

```
var x = {jason: ["2", "5"], alice: ["12", "35"], samuel: ["32", "132"]}
        var out = '';
            $.each(x, function (key, value) {
                out += key + ':';
                var Keyvalue = 0;
                $.each(value, function (key, value) {
                    Keyvalue += parseInt(value, 10);
                });
               out += Keyvalue + " ";
            });

        console.log(out);
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/1ezwwnm1/5/)